# generate tag file from .net librarys(c#) using ctags

Tags: c#, vim, ctags

is there a way to generate a tag file from i.e system.dll ?
maybe some actionscript ones too like Display or Sprite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zeus editor can generate ctags information from any C# assembly, so it is in fact possible, but it does take a little bit of effort.

Zeus does this by exporting the assembly interface to a psuedo C# file and it then runs ctags utility against this psuedo C# file.

C# itself has several APIs that allow you query the details of an assembly so it is not too difficult to write a C# tool that can export the interface of an assembly.

Answer (score 2):

c# is a supported language -- at least under 'exuberant ctags' --  but the nature of the tool is that it generates tags from source files.  I don't think ctags can generate tags from .dll's in any language.  Is the source for system.dll included with .net?

You may want to read more about what exactly ctags is and how it works:

[Wikipedia entry for ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags)

Answer (score 2):

Download the program called [Reflector for .NET](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

- How to use it :

  1. launch it.
  2. select your .NET version
  3. File > Open, select your dll
  4. In the node tree, right click on the function you want to see "Disassemble"
  5. enjoy ;)

Then use ctags -R

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to write a script to do this, then you could use Telerik's JustDecompile (which is free and offers a command line interface), and then run ctags on the resulting directory.

An example from their website:

```
JustDecompile.exe [/lang:csharp] /out:[OutputDirectory] /target:[PathAndAssemblyName].
```